# SSAS - Custom Total

Tags: sql, database, ssas, data-warehouse

I'm trying to create a cube where the total is taken from an attribute on the fact and not calculated as an aggregate of the children in SSAS 2005.  For example

Assume I have 10 stores which all had 100 customers visit on a particular day.  There was however some overlap where some customer visited multiple stores.  The total visitors for the region to which all the stores belong therefore is a manual figure provided in the fact data e.g.

```
Storename  Date  StoreTotal  RegionTotal  
Store 1  2008-01-01  10  95  
Store 2  2008-01-01  13  95  
Store 3  2008-01-01  11  95
```

etc etc

How can I design the cube, using a calculated measure presumably, to return the attribute as the aggregate total instead of summing the measure from the children?

Looking forward to any ideas.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an MDX statement in the cube to return the alternative measure at total level. The problem I had then was that it was returned for every row at leaf level and therefore the total was summing the RegionTotal where I only wanted the first entry. I ended up removing all but 1 region total per key combination which returns the correct result but is a really dirty workaround.  I'll try to come back to this at some point unless someone far more proficient in MDX can come up with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Er, if I understand correctly you are trying to return `RegionTotal` as is? How about setting "Aggregate Function" for the measure to "None".

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I try the Aggregate Function at None then no rows get returned at all.  I'm honestly starting to think this isn't a valid use of SSAS anyway, certainly not in a cube browsing capacity.  It's almost as though it needs a custom report with some logic there like SSRS.

Comment: You could (maybe) modify fact table so that region total contains store's (estimated) contribution to the total, that way the region totals would roll-up.

Comment: Damir,  thanks again for your help.  I've actually got something working which is a horrible hack.  It involves a SCOPE statement in the cube to return the alternative measure at total level. The problem I had then was that it was returned for every row at leaf level and therefore the total was summing the RegionTotal where I only wanted the first entry.  I ended up removing all but 1 region total per key combination which returns the correct result but I'm sure you'll agree is very ugly.  Thanks again for your suggestions and when I get chance to update the data model I'll tackle it again.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a distinct count measure based on the CustomerID? The cube would then calculate this for you and you would not have to do any sort of manual manipulation.